# Warming message: 'tput' cols' had status 2

Tags: r, unix

I get the following warning when running R. It comes up when I start up R and also in some packages that that print output to the console such as status bar.

```
Warning message:
In system2("tput", "cols", stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''tput' cols' had status 2
```

Despite extensive search I cannot find information on this warning. Can anyone help diagnose and fix it?

Comment: Does running just `tput cols` in a terminal (in a shell, not in R) return the expected value, that is, the number of columns that that terminal has?

Comment: I get 80 when I enter that command. What should I expect? I get 80 also when I run that command on another machine that doesn't give the same warnings in R.